# Why do we have an "India" tag?

Tags: support, tags

It has come to my attention that we have questions tagged [india](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/india).  Why do we need this tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't have any other country-specific tags. I don't think this one is necessary.

Comment: Agreed, it shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the earliest questions tagged are about India and Indian phone/network specific issues (regardless of whether they've been closed). In this case the tags do help scope down answers and answerers.

The two questions tagged India this week had nothing country specific in them, and could apply equally to anyone in any country. I've removed the "India" tag from those questions.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the rare case where such a tag could be useful.  Indian phone networks are weird.  That said, at least one of the two remaining open questions is not India-specific and the other is a shopping rec.  So currently the tag has no real use...